# https image does'nt displayed if I force in http

Tags: php, html, image, http, https

In my code, I force the images to load http. However some users hosting their images also get images with https because they are hosted on secure servers and suddenly, they are not displayed on my site. How to display them, without changing my source code of the application
By default, when I display an image :

```
<img src="http://-HERE url of the image without http or https-">
```

Comment: Why do you want to force the http protocol ?

Comment: I'm working on an old code developped by another. And I can't modify this code currently...

Comment: Then the best think to do is hope the server where image are hosted redirect http to https when images are on https. It should work in most case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the protocol provided by the user.

They can host different content on http and https. You can't know it.

The protocol is part of the uri, like the domain or the path. You can't decide it for others.

The only problem is if your website use https: you can't include http images without mixed-content issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to ignore the protocol from the url, like:

```
<img src='//example.com/images/img001.jpg' alt='' title='' />
```

I have seen this done with scripts so it might be worth a go!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Javascript function 'onerror' and change http to https,  to try and solve the problem of it occurs, so it would look like this%

`<img src="url" onError="yourerrorfunction()" >`

Don't forget to break if it's already https to make sure it doesn't end up becoming an infinite loop

Comment: When down voting an answer it's always nice to know why,  as I posted this answer from personal experience and prior knowledge, and now someone apparently does not agree without telling me why. Cade to enlighten me oh mysterious down voter?